# How add attribute to Soap

Tags: php, xml

There is a structure

```
    <Subject SbjKey="1">
        <SbjType>Y</SbjType>
    </Subject>
```

How add SbjKey?

I made an array:

```
    $params->{'Subject SbjKey="1"'} =  new \stdClass();
    $params->{'Subject SbjKey="1"'}->SbjType  = 'Y';
```

In the end I have

```
    <Subject SbjKey="1">
    <SbjType>Y</SbjType>
    </Subject SbjKey="1">
```

How can I get rid of **SbjKey="1"** in this place </Subject **SbjKey="1**"> ?

I send using this method

```
    $client->__soapCall("Function", array($params), null, array($header))
```

UPDATE:

I found a way. This may be a "crutch", but it works.

```
    $SubjectVar = new SoapVar(
    "<Subject SbjKey=\"1\"> 
        <SbjType>Y</SbjType> 
    </Subject>"
    , XSD_ANYXML);
    
    $params->Subject = $SubjectVar;
```

Comment: Not sure if https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php#90161 helps as I'm not sure how to test it.

Comment: I found a way.
This may be a "crutch", but it works.


$SubjectVar = new \SoapVar(
'<Subject SbjKey="1">
        <SbjType>Y</SbjType>
    </Subject>',
 XSD_ANYXML);
$params->Subject =  $SubjectVar;